# Passing a method argument to a class

Tags: python, class, oop

I have the following callable:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, expr, return_status):

        self._expr = expr
        self._status = return_status


    def __call__(self):   

        if self._expr == self._status:
            return True

    def __str__(self):

        return ("Function: %s\n     Return Status: %s\n" %
                (self.__class__.__name__, self._status))
```

The problem I am facing is this that whenever I try to pass an expression like:

```
some_variable = SomeFunction(SomeClass.some_method,return_status=True)
```

`SomeClass.some_method` gets evaluated and gets stored in `self._expr` as a boolean value.

What I actually want is this expression (`SomeClass.some_method`) be stored in `self._expr` and get evaluated each time the `__call__(self)` method is called.

Am I making sense?

Let's say I am taking the following example:

```
def addition(c,b):
        print "'addition' function called!\n"
        sum = c+b
        if sum>5:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    script_timeout = 3


    some_variable = SomeFunction(addition(1,2),return_status=True)

    print "some_variable: \n%s" %some_variable

    some_class.some_method(some_variable, script_timeout, 1)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
'addition' function called!

SomeFunction (_init_) function called!

expr: False

self._expr = False and self._status = True

SomeFunction (_str_) function called!

self.__class__.__name__ = SomeFunction and self._expr = False

monitor: 
Function: SomeFunction
     Return Status of the Expression: True

SomeFunction (_call_) function called!

self._expr = False and self._status = True

SomeFunction (_call_) function called!

self._expr = False and self._status = True

SomeFunction (_call_) function called!

self._expr = False and self._status = True
```

So, the concern is the **addition** function is not getting called with each iteration calling of **SomeFunction** (by the **some_method** method.)

The required functionality is this that **SomeFunction** (when called by **some_method**) should call the function **addition**.

Comment: There is nothing in your `__init__` function that would cause `some_method` to be called.

Comment: We can't help you right now. You need to be precise about what your code is supposed to do, what it is actually doing and provide concrete inputs and outputs that show the faulty and the desired behavior.

Comment: You're never calling the function object stored in `self._expr`. Possibly you just want `self._expr()` inside your `__call__` method?

Comment: Okay, thanks. 
I have edited the question giving an example of the use case; will you be able to help me now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `expr` will be a method/function and assuming you know what method/function returns, you have 3 options. Follow just one of these 3 options and you'll achieve what you want.

1) You can call `expr` in the assignement to `self.expr`:

```
....
class CheckStatus:
    def __init__(self, expr, ...)
        self.expr = expr() # expr() being called here, store whatever the result is to self.expr

    def __call__(self):
        # self.expr already holds a boolean value, or anything your expr returns
        if self.expr == self.status:
            # self.expr match ...
            # do what else you have to do

obj = CheckStatus(SomeClass().method, ...) # pay attention how we pass the method here
```

2) If `self.expr` is a reference to that `expr`, then:

```
class CheckStatus:
    def __init__(self, expr, ...):
        self.expr = expr

    def __call__(self):
        # in this example, self.expr now it's a reference to some method
        # thus you need to call self.expr here
        if self.expr() == self.status:
            ....

obj = CheckStatus(SomeClass().method, ...) # pay attention how we pass method for this example
```

3) call the `SomeClass().method()` at instantiation of `CheckStatus()`:

```
class CheckStatus:
    def __init__(self, expr, ...):
        self.expr = expr # for this example, expr already is a boolean or anything else some method/function returned

    def __call__(self):
        # don't need to call anything here
        if self.expr == self.status:
            ....

obj = CheckStatus(SomeClass().method(), ...) # because here we called SomeClass().method()
```

You have to call the method/function your passing in to your `CheckStatus` class somewhere, otherwise you'll never have that method/function result to check.
Hope it was clear.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. :/

TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: @VishalKNair, That is very clear. That exception means you trying to call some variable, maybe `expr`, which already is holding a boolean value. You must take care of it. In my answer, I tried to give you 3 examples of what you could do, but don't don't apply the 3 at the same time. Just chose one and stick with it. I'll update my answer so it be a bit more clear.

Comment: Thank you so much! The second one worked. I just have one last query: I believe this won't work if the method called is used with a @property decorator; what changes should be made then?

Comment: @Vishal K Nair if it has a decorator `@property` then it can't be used as method, but instead as a property, thus it would be `SomeClass().method` assuming it has `@property` decorator and in `CheckResult` you'd use `self.expr` only without parentheses.  And, I think you might need some extra lines of code to the `__call__` method to check whether a method is indeed a method or it is a property.

Answer (score -2):

```
class S(object):
    def __init__(self, expr, return_status):
        self._expr = expr
        self._status = return_status

    def __call__(self):   
        if self._expr() == self._status:
            raise Exception
        self._expr()

    def __str__(self):
        return ("Function: %s\n     Return Status of the Expression: %s\n" %
                (self.__class__.__name__, self._status))

def some_method():return True
try:
    S(some_method,return_status=True)()
except Exception as e:
    print('Got Exception')
```

Comment: 1. You don't even know what OP is trying to do or how he magically gets boolean instance attributes. 2. You posted code without any explanation. => Your answer is premature, therefore -1.